# Express loads infinity and doesn't work when using Express body Parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parsing

I have implemented an API with Express, but the API no longer works as soon as I use the body parser integrated in Express. When I call the API, the request takes an infinitely long time to load and Express simply doesn't react to it. As soon as I stop using the body parser, requests work again without any problems.

Code:

```js
const Express = require("express")
const db = require("./database")

const app = Express()

app.use(Express.json)

app.get("/api", ((req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("The API is working")
}))

app.post("/api/user/:id/settings",(req, res) => {
  console.log("It works")
  db.edit({user: req.params.id}, req.body, "user").catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send(err)
    console.error(err)
  }).then(() => {
    res.status(200)
  })
})

app.listen(3000)
console.log("API is ready")
```

Node.js Version: `16.0.0`
express Version: `4.17.1`

Comment: It's `app.use(Express.json())`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that resolved the problem